# Sorting array returns wrong value

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have made a function that finds the closest element that is smaller and bigger from a user's input.

To manage this I've used the `.last()` and `.first()` methods.

```
func closestNumbers(_ column: [String], value: Int) {                           
    // Gets the closest element in array to userInput
    let userInput = value

    let rangeA = column

    let left = rangeA.last(where: { $0  <=  String(userInput)})!      // last element that is less or equal to userInput
    let right = rangeA.first(where: { $0 >= String(userInput)})!    // first element that is bigger or the same as userInput


    print(left, userInput, right)
    // prints   left <= userInput >= right
}
```

EXAMPLE: If the userInput would be 450 in an array of [100, 200, .... , 1000].

The print should return (400, 450, 500)

However, it returns 1000, 450, 500.

Even though I feel the logic is correct.

Comment: It's correct. In terms of `String` `"1000"` is less than `"400"`. Just compare the integers

Comment: Why you cast your numbers in `String`, you should cast them in `Int` or `Double` instead. Edit: As @vadian said its most likely due to this cast

Comment: I suspected that, thanks ill try that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare *strings* not the *numbers* here:

```
let left = rangeA.last(where: { $0  <=  String(userInput)})!
let right = rangeA.first(where: { $0 >= String(userInput)})!
```

This means that they will be compared in the dictionary order, or *lexicographically*. In dictionary order, `1000` comes before `450`, so it is "less than" `450`. And since `1000` is the last element in the array, it is chosen as the last one that is less than 450.

You should instead convert the array elements to `Int` and compare the `Int`s instead:

```
let left = rangeA.last(where: { Int($0)!  <=  userInput})!
let right = rangeA.first(where: { Int($0)! >= userInput})!
```

In fact, why not just make the parameter type an `[Int]` instead of a `[String]`?

```
func closestNumbers(_ column: [Int], value: Int) {
```

Then you don't need any conversion at all.

Note that this will only work if `rangeA` is sorted. If `rangeA` is not guaranteed to be sorted, you have to sort it first.

Comment: It makes a lot more sense now, the reason why I did it like this was because the array of values I get from a csv file where it was as Strings. And I couldn't figure out how to get them as Ints. Beginner mistakes all over I guess. But thank you this cleared up a lot. Cheers all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to not use String but Int instead

```
func closestNumbers(_ column: [Int], value: Int) -> (Int?, Int, Int?) {                           
    return (column.last(where: { $0  <  value}), value, column.first(where: { $0 > value}))
}

let arr = Array(0...20).map { $0 * 50 }

print(closestNumbers(arr, value: 450))
```